# ArrayList is reinitialising when a method is called

Tags: java, arraylist

I was having a problem in getting my history back from a class using an arraylist of objects of that class as every time a method is called the arraylist reinitialise itself
Here's my code:

```
public class User_Interface2 {
    ArrayList<Removable> re=new ArrayList<Removable>();
    private final ArrayList<Internal> in=new ArrayList<Internal>();
    ArrayList<External> ex=new ArrayList<External>();

public static void main(){
User_Interface2 q=new User_Interface2();
    System.out.println("Choose from the below options");
    System.out.println("1.Internal Storage");
    System.out.println("2.Removable device");
    System.out.println("3.External Drive");
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");

    String s=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the file in GB");
    double d=sc.nextDouble();

    q.saveData(a,s,d);


}
public void saveData(int a,String s,double d){

    switch (a) {
        case 1:

            in.add(new Internal());
            in.get(in.size()-1).nameoffile=s;
            in.get(in.size()-1).size=d;

            in.get(in.size()-1).capacity();

            break;
        case 2:
            re.add(new Removable());

            re.get(re.size()-1).nameoffile=s;
            re.get(re.size()-1).size=d;

            re.get(re.size()-1).capacity();

            break;
        case 3:
            ex.add(new External());

            ex.get(ex.size()-1).nameoffile=s;
            ex.get(ex.size()-1).size=d;

            ex.get(ex.size()-1).capacity();

            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No such storage option available");
            break;
    }

}
```

}

and this is the internal class:

```
public class Internal extends Storage {
static double capacity=1024;
String nameoffile;
public double size;
void capacity(){
    capacity=capacity-size;
    System.out.println("Remaining capacity: "+capacity+"GB");
}
void persistent_save(){}
```

}

whenever the main method of the User_Interface2 class is called from the another class and data is stored in internal class , after exiting this class the arraylist gets cleared itself and I am not able to see the history of the stored data.

this is my method from which User_Interface2 class is being called:

```
void Laptop(){
    User_Interface2 d;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Your Laptop");
    System.out.println("Choose from the below options");
    System.out.println("1.Show details of the laptop");
    System.out.println("2.Display the data stored in your laptop");
    System.out.println("3.Save Data");

    System.out.println("4.Charge your Laptop");
    System.out.println("0 to exit");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    while(a!=0){
    if(a==1)
    {processor();
    Ram();
    MotherBoard();}
    else if(a==2)
    {d=new User_Interface2();
    d.showData();}
    else if(a==3)
    {d=new User_Interface2();
    d.main();}

    else if(a==4)
    {charge();}
   else
    {System.out.println("No such Option is available");}
   System.out.println("Welcome to Your Laptop");
    System.out.println("Choose from the below options");
    System.out.println("1.Show details of the laptop");
    System.out.println("2.Display the data stored in your laptop");
    System.out.println("3.Save Data");

    System.out.println("4.Charge your Laptop");
    System.out.println("0 to exit");
    //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    a=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
}
}
```

}

Comment: In the loop, you have `{d=new User_Interface2();` If you create a new instance, the member variable will be instanciated again too (including the list). If I am wrong, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I downvoted your question simply because of the bad formatting of the code. If you expect people to help you, at least put in the effort of making it easy for them.

Comment: And seriously: use variable names that mean something. a, d, ... it almost feels like you tried to write code that is hard for us to read. You see: if your formatting and naming would be better ... maybe you yourself could understand what your code is doing? Instead of then looking to other people "help me deciper this cryptic stuff"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick review of that block :

```
while(a!=0){
... 
else if(a==2)
{d=new User_Interface2();
d.showData();}
else if(a==3)
{d=new User_Interface2();
d.main();}
}
```

You are creating a new instance on each iteration.
Create `d` outside the loop and reuse that instance.

```
d=new User_Interface2();
while(a!=0){
    ...
    else if(a==2) {
        d.showData();
    } else if(a==3) {
        d.main();
    }
}
```